# Dll changes or not if i do change in my web.config file

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I have UPDATED my web.config code , now i have to send patch for the changed code to be deployed on the production.
I am not sure that .dll file should be send along with web.config file or not?

if yes then why?
if not then why?

Thanks.

Comment: It would be helpful to know exactly what you changed in your web.config.

Comment: I do changed in the tag <pages/> and tag <httpRuntime requestValidationMode="2.0"/>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You dont need to send over the dll, unless there is a change in the code.

Because, web.config is a meant for configuration and has no affect on dll. web.config is read as it is. ***the purpose of placing things is web.config, to keep things configurable with out changing the code***

Comment: This is not necessarily true.

Comment: What if there was a configuration change that created a dependency on new code.  E.g.: adding a new handler/module.

Comment: then you are responsible for the change, Configuration file is not responsible for any change to comply with version of dll(s)

Comment: That's also not true.  Binding redirects are very common in web.config.